# Implement dictionary-like class

Tags: typescript

Shouldn't this be possible?

```
interface IDictionary {
    [index: string]: string;
}

class Dictionary implements IDictionary {
    public foo = "bar";
}
```

Instead I'm getting the error:

```
TS2420:Class 'Dictionary' incorrectly implements 'IDictionary'. Index signature is missing in type 'Dictionary'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you implement an interface

```
interface IDictionary {
    [index: string]: string;
}

class Dictionary implements IDictionary {
    public foo = "bar";
}
```

you need provide all requirement

```
interface IDictionary {
    [index: string]: string;
}

class Dictionary implements IDictionary {
    public foo = "bar";
    [index: string]: string;
}
```